# Segmentation fault when passing function pointer

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am using Solaris. The code where i am getting segmentation fault is inside .so .We have few static functions, basically these functions are callback functions. I set these functions as callback functions by passing its address to another function. Only for one of the function its address before passing as an argument looks correct , but after stepping into the function to set the function pointer, it changed into some junk pointer and calling the function by that pointer crashes.
I am putting some sample code, its not the actual  code, but it is similar to that.

In A.cpp, i have three callback functions

```
static void Func1(A* ptr)
{
}

static void Func2(A* ptr)
{
}

static void Func3(A* ptr)
{
}
```

In one register function, i assign these as callback functions

```
void vRegisterCallback(void (*ptrToFunc)(void*))
{
}

void Register()
{
    vRegisterCallback(void (*)(void*)Func1);
    vRegisterCallback(void (*)(void*)Func2);
    vRegisterCallback(void (*)(void*)Func3);
}
```

I register three function as like above.
`Func1` pointer is valid, but when it is passed as an argument to `vRegisterCallback`.  `vRegisterCallback` is having different address than `Func1`.

If I add a `printf` statement above it works with valid pointer sent to `vRegisterCallback`.
If I change the `Func1` from static to non static it works...
If I change the .so to .a , it works.

Dont know what is the problem.

Comment: Are you generating position independent code (-fpic)?

Comment: I would suspect stack corruption.  Add a watchpoint to the variable holding the function pointer and run your code within `gdb`.

Comment: I believe casting from one function pointer to another is a non-standard extension. So you will have to mention which compiler that is used. Perhaps your compiler does not support it.

Comment: Your program invokes undefined behavior: function pointers arr expected to be of type `void (*)(void *)` but actually they're of type `void (*)(A *)`.

Comment: Your example won't even compile.

Comment: Code Clown : I am using -fpic.
Lundin : We are using solaris studio 12.3 compiler. Earlier we were using solaris SUNwspro compiler, we didnt have these problem. THese type of casting is there in our complete code base, this is the common code for registering we use. After changing the compiler we are getting this problem for only one of the function pointer.